# Laptop doesn't detect my wifi signal

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I have recently installed Linux Mint on my laptop and have updated the wireless drivers. My laptop detects all wireless signals around but not mine. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: That sounds like a router issue, not a laptop problem. Do you use other WiFi devices? Have you checked the WiFi status of your router?

Comment: And did the laptop ever connect to that router, when running any other OS? Or can it connect to other WiFi sources (routers) when running that Linux Mint?

Comment: @Sukminder : no , I don't think it's a router issue as I am connected with it using other devices.

Comment: @Xen2050 : Yes , When I was using windows before.

Comment: Check what channel your router is using.

Comment: If the same laptop worked with the same router (same config & everything), then it would appear to be a Mint/kernel software/driver/config problem. I'd check if Mint can connect to any other WiFi's, of none work (I have some USB wifi adapters that just won't work with Mint/Ubuntu, sometimes see networks & attempt to connect but don't work at all) there ight be some things to try, I remember seeing some "broadcom" attempted fixes on askubuntu.com but don't have them handy

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) the make and model of your laptop ii) the make and model of your wifi card (`lspci | grep -i network`) iii) the fact that it worked under windows and that you connect with other devices (such things are easy to miss in the comments) iv) the version of mint you are using v) the driver you are using vi) the channel your wifi is on. Can your driver support that channel?